# Can I show an image with BIOS interrupts or assembly?

Tags: bios, assembly

I am trying write a simple bootloader, and I want to show an image when my bootloader starts. How can I do this?

I am using assembly with nasm assembler.

Comment: You might want to search the questions then ask on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), as they're more geared toward programming questions than SU is.

Comment: Better on this forum, StackOverflow is not tolerant of humor and general issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what kind of video mode you want use and what to do with the picture. But I think the resources below by almost 100% to answer your questions and create new ones).

[PC Games Programmers Encyclopedia book: archive Zip](http://www.intel-assembler.it/PORTALE/4/pcgpe10.zip)

[PC Games Programmers Encyclopedia part source code](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/rsc/pcgpe-1.0/)

[File Description PCGPE](http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/assembly-game-programming-encyclopedia/assembly-game-programming-encyclopedia.asp)

Good Luck!